# Is it a martingale or not?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Is $X_{T}=\int_{0}^{T}\left(T-t\right)dB_{t}$ process is a martingale in the natural filtration of $B$, where $B$ is a Brownian motion?

I would say it is not a martingale, since $$X_{T}=\int_{0}^{T}TdB_{t}+\int_{0}^{T}\left(-t\right)dB_{t}=TB_{T}+\int_{0}^{T}\left(-t\right)dB_{t}.$$

The second part: $\int_{0}^{T}\left(-t\right)dB_{t}$ is definitely a martingale, but if we decompose the $TB_{T}$ process with the Ito-formula, we get:$$TB_{T}=\int_{0}^{T}B_{t}dt+\int_{0}^{T}tdB_{t},$$ but $\int_{0}^{T}B_{t}dt$ is not a martingale, so $X$ can't be either.

However, I think $\left(T-t\right)$ is progressive measurable, and $$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{T}\left(T-t\right)^{2}dt\right)<\infty\;\;\;\forall T,$$ so according to this, it would yield that $X$ should be a martingale. What do I miss here?

Anyway, $\left(T-t\right)$ isn't a "nice" integrand either. It seems like it is a 2-variable integrand and I don't know how to handle them.What is the correct condition to check if a a stochastic integrale (where the integrator is a Brownian motion) is martingale in this (“2-variable”) case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that if $T_{1}\le T_{2}$ then
\begin{multline*}
X_{T_{2}}
=\int_{0}^{T_{2}}\left(T_{2}-T_{1}\right)dB_{t}
+\int_{0}^{T_{2}}\left(T_{1}-t\right)dB_{t}
=\left(T_{2}-T_{1}\right)B_{T_{2}}+X_{T_{1}}
+\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left(T_{1}-t\right)dB_{t}
\end{multline*}
and, taking expectations,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(X_{T_{2}}\mid \mathcal{F}_{T_{1}}\right)
=X_{T_{1}}+\left(T_{2}-T_{1}\right)B_{T_{1}}+0.$$
That second term makes me think not a martingale.

$(T-t)$ I would not call a process at all, hence the problem applying your theorem from progressive measurability.

Comment: As I remember (stochastic) processes are defined as  two variable functions (the function of $t$ and $\omega$). Is the problem here that it is a 3 variable function? Or why wouldn't you call it a process?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I meant. Now looking at your working again, I think I prefer it to mine. $d\!\left(t B_{t}\right)=B_{t}dt+t\,dB_{t}$ so $dX_{t}=B_{t}dt$ and $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X_{T_{2}}\left\lvert \mathcal{F}_{T_{1}}\right.\right)=X_{T_{1}}+\mathbb{E}\!\left(\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}B_{t}dt\left\lvert \mathcal{F}_{T_{1}}\right.\right)$.